# PHP5 - I want to write a Hindi text on image

Tags: php, image, text, utf-8

I want to write a Hindi text(say "पुलिसवाला आमिर खान" ) on an image using PHP5.

I am using

```
$im = @imagecreate(210, 50);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 
imagestring($im, 7, 15, 15, utf8_encode("पुलिसवाला आमिर खान..."), $text_color);
ImagePNG($im, 'a.png'); 
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: before you ask here try to search in google.then post what you get.SO not did your homework.

Comment: I've googled a lot but not get any solution to full fill my requirement till now. that's why I'm here.

Comment: Interesting question, but lacks detail. What have you tried? What didn't work? What font(s) are you using?

Comment: you must specify your question, please post more information.the complete question can get the complete answer.

Comment: install hindi font and use :)

Comment: This is my code:
`
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

echo ("पुलिसवाला आमिर खान...");

$im = @imagecreate(210, 50);

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

**imagestring($im, 7, 15, 15,  utf8_encode("पुलिसवाला आमिर खान..."), $text_color);**

ImagePNG($im, 'a.png');

imagedestroy($im);
`

while echo the text is displaying correctly on the browser. but on the image it is not coming correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `imagettftext()` to write text onto images as long as your host supports GD2 and FreeType (as most servers do). You can find its detailed syntax and comments here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Find a font (*.ttf or *.otf) that supports Hindi characters. Put the font file in the same directory as your script, and then try this code -- substituting "yourhindifont.ttf" for your own font filename:

```
    <?php

    // your string, preferably read from a source elsewhere
    $utf8str = "पुलिसवाला आमिर खान";

    // buffer output in case there are errors
    ob_start();

    // create blank image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400,40);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
    imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,imagesx($im),imagesy($im),$white);

    // write the text to image
    $font = "yourhindifont.ttf";
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 50, 50, 50, 0); // dark gray
    $size = 20;
    $angle = 0;
    $x = 5;
    $y = imagesy($im) - 5;
    imagettftext($im, $size, $angle, $x, $y , $color, $font, $utf8str);

    // display the image, if no errors
    $err = ob_get_clean();
    if( !$err ) {
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($im);
    } else {
        header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
        echo $err;
    }

    ?>
```

If you plan to input Hindi directly into your source, be sure to set the document encoding of your source to UTF-8 (without BOM) in your editor beforehand. Otherwise the string will not be stored as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use function [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and hindi font.
Path to font should be absolute (use realpath or just write absolute path).

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely need a  solution that works with a Truetype font, `imagestring()` won't cut it.

1. Get hold of a TTF font containing Hindi characters tht you can use
2. get rid of the `utf8_encode()`, just make sure the file is UTF8 encoded
3. use [`imagefttext()`](http://php.net/imagefttext) instead of `imagestring()`

Comment: @Sayuj there shouldn't be a need for that: If you have your *PHP file* UTF-8 encoded in your editor or IDE, every character in it will be too.

Comment: @Sayuj, you don't need to encode *image* file to UTF-8. What you need to encode is a *source* file which generates an image (or, if text comes from DB, then DB must be properly configured to store UTF-8 data).